# Implement a policy about restrictions between user and sys

Tags: sql, oracle

How to write a policy function as scott to implement the following policy: Users can access only the data of their own, but sysdba should be able to access any data without restrictions, then attach the policy to the table.?

Your answers could be a great help. Thank you.

UPDATE:

```
SCOTT > CREATE FUNCTION POLICY (
p_schema IN VARCHAR2,
p_object IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
if(SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'SESSION_USER') = 'SYS' ) THEN RETURN '';
else 
RETURN 'NAME = SYS_CONTEXT ("USERENV", "SESSION_USER")';
END IF;


SYS AS SYSDBA> EXECUTE DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (object_schema=>'SCOTT', OBJECT_NAME=>'RATING', POLICY_NAME=>'FIRST_POLICY', FUNCTION_SCHEMA=>'SCOTT', POLICY_FUNCTION=>'POLICY', STATEMENT_TYPES=>'SELECT', UPDATE_CHECK=>TRUE);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

ERROR:
`SCOTT > SELECT * FROM RATING;`

SELECT * FROM RATING
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28113: policy predicate has error

Comment: What kind of policy are you talking about? You have literally described the default security posture of every Oracle database, ever. Does this involve Database Vault?

Comment: its just a beginner level assignment, so i think the general command would be fine@pmdba

Comment: What is meant by "user"? A database user, or an application user (which is not necessarily the same thing)?

Comment: By default, database users can only see their own tables, and sysdba can not be restricted. Application users (accessing the DB through the same service account) might have their individual data protected using sys_context and a virtual private database function attached to a table. This would not restrict sysdba either.

Comment: If you're learning about VPD, then please post some code here that you have tried and that we can evaluate. We're not here to do the homework for you. In the meantime, read the documentation and check out the examples: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html#GUID-06022729-9210-4895-BF04-6177713C65A7

Comment: the command is updated@PMDBA

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to restrict data in your table for the users and do not want to restrict data for SYS.
You need to have a column in your table to specify which rows belong to which user.
As an example, I have taken the column USER and it can be something else.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SCOTT_POLICY(schema_in in VARCHAR2, table_in in VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  RESTRICTION VARCHAR2(100);
  SESSION_USER VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
      SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') INTO SESSION_USER FROM DUAL;
    
      RESTRICTION := 'UPPER(USER) = '||DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(SESSION_USER);
      RETURN RESTRICTION;
END;
/
```

Update:

After creating this policy function which will return a predicate if SESSION USER is not SYS. Then the predicate will restrict rows for the users and the query will only show the rows where the USER = (CURRENT SESSION USER) condition satisfies.
If the user is SYS
then the function will not be called and no predicate is appended to the query hence getting all rows.
RLS policies are not applied to SYS users.
To attach policy function with a policy use DBMS_RLS package

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY(OBJECT_SCHEMA => 'SCOTT', OBJECT_NAME => 'YOURTABLENAME', POLICY_NAME => 'SCOTT_POLICY', FUNCTION_SCHEMA => 'SCOTT', POLICY_FUNCTION => 'SCOTT_POLICY');
END;
```

There is more to it but this fulfills your basic requirement.
You may want to check static and dynamic policies, policy groups, or sec_relevant_col option.

Comment: Your check of SESSION_USER='SYS' is unnecessary, as SYS is exempt from VPD policies by definition. If the user is SYS, SYSDBA, etc. then the function will never be called.

Comment: Yes, correct. I have made changes to the answer. Thank you for mentioning it.